# Towers of Hanoi search Algorithm python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, binary-search-tree, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to create a search algorithm for the 3-disk towers of hanoi problem in python. I am trying to create a search algorithm that has frontier managers for a stack, queue, and priority queue. My end goal is so create a tree search program and a graph search program. My current problem that I can't seem to fix whatsoever is to save my path of the states I have visited. If you could analyze my algorithm so far and let me know what I have to do to fix my problem and make my algorithm better. Here is what I have so far:

```
tower1 = [3, 2, 1]
tower2 = []
tower3 = []
stack1 = []
stack2 = []
stack3 = []
state = [tower1, tower2, tower3]
realfrontier = []

def readstate1(tower1):
    if not tower1:
        stack1.append(4)
    else:
        stack1.append(tower1[-1])

def readstate2(tower2):
    if not tower2:
        stack2.append(4)
    else:
        stack2.append(tower2[-1])       

def readstate3(tower3):
    if not tower3:
        stack3.append(4)
    else:
        stack3.append(tower3[-1])

def readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3):
    readstate1(tower1), readstate2(tower2), readstate3(tower3)

def buildfrontier(frontier):
    realfrontier.append(eval(frontier[0]))
    del frontier

def validmove12(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    if stack1[-1] < stack2[-1]:
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        print (state)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    else:
        print ('move12 not valid')

def validmove13(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    if stack1[-1] < stack3[-1]:
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        print (state)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    else:
        print ('move13 not valid')


def validmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    if stack2[-1] < stack1[-1]:
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        print (state)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
    else:
        tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def validmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    if stack2[-1] < stack3[-1]:
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        print (state)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    else:
        print ('move23 not valid')

def validmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    if stack3[-1] < stack1[-1]:
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        print (state)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    else:
        print ('move31 not valid')

def validmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    if stack3[-1] < stack2[-1]:
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        print (state)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    else:
        print ('move32 not valid')

def tryvalidmove13(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack1[-1] < stack3[-1]:
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3)

    else:
        tryvalidmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack2[-1] < stack1[-1]:
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack2[-1] < stack3[-1]:
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack3[-1] < stack1[-1]:
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack3[-1] < stack2[-1]:
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)


def tryvalidmove12(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack1[-1] < stack2[-1]:
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove13(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove13(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove13(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack1[-1] < stack3[-1]:
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove21(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack2[-1] < stack1[-1]:
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove23(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack2[-1] < stack3[-1]:
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3)


def tryvalidmove31(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack3[-1] < stack1[-1]:
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower1.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower1.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        tryvalidmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3)
    else:
        tryvalidmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3)

def tryvalidmove32(stack1, stack2, stack3):
    if stack3[-1] < stack2[-1]:
        object1 = tower3.pop()
        tower2.append(object1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        object1 = tower2.pop()
        tower3.append(object1)
        readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)

def neighbors(tower1, tower2, tower3):
    readstatefull(tower1, tower2, tower3)
    tryvalidmove12(stack1, stack2, stack3)

newtower1 = []
newtower2 = []
newtower3 = []

def newneighbors(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3):
    readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
    trynewvalidmove12(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)


newstack1 = []
newstack2 = []
newstack3 = []

def readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3):
    readnewstate1(newtower1), readnewstate2(newtower2),    readnewstate3(newtower3)


def readnewstate1(newtower1):
    if not newtower1:
        newstack1.append(4)
    else:
        newstack1.append(newtower1[-1])


def readnewstate2(newtower2):
    if not newtower2:
        newstack2.append(4)
    else:
        newstack2.append(newtower1[-1])


def readnewstate3(newtower1):
    if not newtower3:
        newstack3.append(4)
    else:
        newstack3.append(newtower1[-1])


def trynewvalidmove12(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack1[-1] < newstack2[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower1.pop()
        newtower2.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower2.pop()
        newtower1.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        trynewvalidmove13(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)
    else:
        trynewvalidmove13(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)

def trynewvalidmove13(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack1[-1] < newstack3[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower1.pop()
        newtower3.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower3.pop()
        newtower1.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        trynewvalidmove21(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)
    else:
        trynewvalidmove21(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)

def trynewvalidmove21(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack2[-1] < newstack1[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower2.pop()
        newtower1.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower2.pop()
        newtower2.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        trynewvalidmove23(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)
    else:
        trynewvalidmove23(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)

def trynewvalidmove23(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack2[-1] < newstack3[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower2.pop()
        newtower3.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower3.pop()
        newtower3.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        trynewvalidmove31(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)
    else:
        trynewvalidmove31(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)


def trynewvalidmove23(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack2[-1] < newstack3[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower2.pop()
        newtower3.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower3.pop()
        newtower2.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        trynewvalidmove31(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)
    else:
        trynewvalidmove31(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)

def trynewvalidmove31(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack3[-1] < newstack1[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower3.pop()
        newtower1.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower1.pop()
        newtower3.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        trynewvalidmove32(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)
    else:
        trynewvalidmove32(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3)


def trynewvalidmove32(newstack1, newstack2, newstack3):
    if newstack3[-1] < newstack2[-1]:
        newobject1 = newtower3.pop()
        newtower2.append(newobject1)
        print (state)
        frontier = []
        frontier.append(str(state))
        buildfrontier(frontier)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
        newobject1 = newtower2.pop()
        newtower3.append(newobject1)
        readnewstatefull(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)

def cleanupnewtowers(holdtower1, holdtower2, holdtower3)
        global newtower1
        global newtower2
        global newtower3
        newtower1 = holdtower1[0][:]
        newtower2 = holdtower2[0][:]
        newtower3 = holdtower3[0][:]
        global newstate
        newstate = [newtower1, newtower2, newtower3]   

 def firstinfirstout(realfrontier):
       if not realfrontier:
        neighbors(tower1, tower2, tower3)
        print ('frontier established')
    else:
        newchoice = realfrontier.pop(0)
        holdtower1 = []
        holdtower2 = []
        holdtower3 = []
        holdtower1.append(newchoice[0])
        holdtower2.append(newchoice[1])
        holdtower3.append(newchoice[2]
        cleanupnewtowers(holdtower1, holdtower2, holdtower3)
        newneighbors(newtower1, newtower2, newtower3)
```

Comment: You have a lot of duplication. Pass the next `tryvalidmove` as a parameter, and only implement `validmove` once.

Comment: what do you mean? I should put tryvalidmove as a parameter of the next tryvalidmove or validmove?